# Any alternative to "on the one hand, on the other hand"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

I'm writing a formal academic article to introduce some facts. For example:

> On the one hand, the government would like more energy, but on the other hand, it is not prepared to find more extra investments in order to get it.

However, I think the idiom *on the one hand...on the other hand* is somewhat informal. Are there any, more formal alternative to this idiom, that would fit in the provided context?

Comment: *While*? While apples are crunchy, oranges are nice as well!

Comment: Related: [Academic way of saying “On the other hand”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50616/academic-way-of-saying-on-the-other-hand/50702#50702) and [Overuse of “however” in my scientific writing?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242184/overuse-of-however-in-my-scientific-writing)

Comment: Also related: [Difference between nevertheless and nonetheless](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72134/difference-between-nevertheless-and-nonetheless) Don't just limit to looking at the suggestions, take note on *how* the answerers reply!

Answer (score 8):

The [discourse marker](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/soc/al/learning_english/leap/grammar/discourse/), or sentence connector used by the OP; ["on the one hand ... on the other hand"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/on-the-one-hand-on-the-other-hand) expresses two *contrasting*  ideas, opinions or facts. It is a perfectly acceptable expression in formal papers; however, there is nothing to prevent it from being shortened to “on the other hand”.

Nevertheless, I suggest the following alternatives:

- The government would like more energy, **on the other hand** it is not prepared to find more investments in order to obtain it
- **Although** the government would like more energy, it is not prepared . . .
- The government would like more energy; **however**, it is not prepared . . .
- The government would like more energy, **although** it is not prepared . . .
- **Despite the fact** the government would like more energy, it is not prepared . . .
- **Even though** the government would like more energy, it is not prepared . . .
- The government would like more energy. **Yet** it is not prepared . . .

> [Transitional Words and Phrases](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Transitions.html)
>    **Contrast**
>   •yet •and yet •nevertheless •nonetheless •after all •but •however •though •otherwise •on the contrary •in contrast •notwithstanding •on the other hand •at the same time
>
> <sup>Source: The Writing Centre, UW-Madison</sup>